# Bison malloc memory corruption

Tags: c++, c, bison

I was trying to compile from git source for Asterisk Open-Source PBX and almost immediately after running `./configure` I hit a rather unusual error when it comes to checking bison's support for parse-param it hits a kind of segfault, or rather a memory corruption making the process come to a complete halt by hanging at the caught memory corruption.

```
checking for bison that supports parse-param... *** Error in `/usr/bin/bison': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00000000011d8760 ***
*** Error in `/usr/bin/bison': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00007f4c5affd010 ***
```

I'm not really sure what caused this or why this error is happening. I have all the things I needed installed for compiling Asterisk.

if it helps I did a trace of the command and this what it outputted for bison;

```
strace /usr/bin/bison

execve("/usr/bin/bison", ["/usr/bin/bison"], [/* 49 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xf28000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f922f48a000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=174223, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 174223, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f922f45f000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\265\5\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=979056, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f922f45e000
mmap(NULL, 3159072, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f922ef66000
mprotect(0x7f922f04c000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f922f24b000, 40960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xe5000) = 0x7f922f24b000
mmap(0x7f922f255000, 82976, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f922f255000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0T\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1063328, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3158344, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f922ec62000
mprotect(0x7f922ed65000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f922ef64000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x102000) = 0x7f922ef64000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360*\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=88408, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2184224, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f922ea4c000
mprotect(0x7f922ea61000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f922ec60000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14000) = 0x7f922ec60000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\36\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1853400, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f922f45d000
mmap(NULL, 3961912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f922e684000
mprotect(0x7f922e841000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f922ea41000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bd000) = 0x7f922ea41000
mmap(0x7f922ea47000, 17464, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f922ea47000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f922f45c000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f922f45a000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f922f45a740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f922ea41000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f922ec60000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f922ef64000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f922f459000
mprotect(0x7f922f24b000, 32768, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f922f48b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f922f45f000, 174223)          = 0
write(2, "/usr/bin/bison: no grammar file "..., 38/usr/bin/bison: no grammar file given
) = 38
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: It is possible that the version of bison in your system has a bug that prevents it from being used to build PBX. I'd suggest upgrading bison if you can (you can check its version number by doing `bison --version`), but also checking the actual bison input that failed by having a look into the file `configure.log` that was probably generated by `./configure` (if not, run ./configure --help to see how to generate it).

Comment: I checked the version of bison installed and I have; `bison++ Version 1.21.9-1, adapted from GNU bison by coetmeur@icdc.fr
Maintained by Magnus Ekdahl <magnus@debian.org>` I did check if I could update it, but it's already on the latest I could get from my distribution repository. As for the configure log, I couldn't see anything that pointed to bison.

Comment: bison++ != bison, and it shouldn't be installed as /usr/bin/bison.

Comment: I assumed that was the fault of his distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Asterisk source it appears you don't actually need Bison for it to compile. It will normally use the already generated C files instead. If the crash is preventing the configure script from running to completion then run  itwith `./configure BISON=/bin/true` and that should let it finish.

Alternatively you can download the last GNU bison source, compile, install it and then point the Asterisk configure script at it with `BISON=/path/to/bison`. I'd recommend getting the regular GNU bison source over whatever version of bison++ your distribution is using. The GNU version might not have the same bug and it's more likely to have the "parse-param" feature the configure script is testing for.

This bug appears to have already been reported in the Ubuntu bug tracker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bison++/+bug/80975